# What is tinkerpop?

Tags: graph, tinkerpop

How the forum TinkerPop can be addressed? Is it going to specify a standard for the Graph DBs and the related technology Frameworks? In this effort TinkerPop is considered as an authority or pioneer in some sense? I was not able to understand these by going through TinkerPop homepage.Thanks.

Comment: Googling could not help much on this. And there is no such question so far. The homepage of TinkerPop does not explain so well. Hence asking this.

Comment: I agree, this is a very plausible question and I was wondering the very same thing myself, so thanks for being the pioneer. I am still kinda confused about the relation between Titan and TinkerPop.

Comment: @innuendo Titan implements TinkerPop's APIs and therefore gets access to all the features of TinkerPop, like the Gremlin query language, Gremlin Server, Spark integration, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TinkerPop is just the name of the project that contains Blueprints and the other projects you see on the TinkerPop [home page](http://tinkerpop.com).  It is not on its own a project or library that you can use, rather just the name of the suite of tools for the graph technology space.

TinkerPop also refers to the [collection of individuals](https://github.com/tinkerpop?tab=members) (many of whom are representatives from different graph database vendors, such as [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/), [Titan](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com), [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/), [Bitsy](https://bitbucket.org/lambdazen/bitsy/wiki/Home), etc.)  One might think of TinkerPop as a graph technology [guild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guild) or fellowship.

TinkerPop is not a specification, mandate or standard for writing graph applications, nor does it aspire to be.  TinkerPop merely provides a set of interfaces that graph database vendors can implement (Blueprints) to get all the features of the rest of the TinkerPop stack (Pipes, Frames, Rexster, Furnace, and Gremlin) where each part of the stack provides a specific function in supporting graph-based application development.

**UPDATE:** As of version 3.x, TinkerPop is an Apache project - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/.  Under 3.x, TinkerPop no longer has individual separate projects such as Blueprints, Pipes, etc.  It is all a single project repository that has folded in all of those projects.

Comment: What is the objective of TinkerPop? Is it going to serve as a set of specifications that are going to be implemented by many?

Comment: http://www.garshol.priv.no/blog/231.html compares as TinkerPop as a triplestore

Comment: I've amended my answer a bit.  TinkerPop's primary objective is to provide open source tools for the graph technology space.  That's it.  I think that you should frame questions and look for answers more in the context of the individual projects of TinkerPop rather than TinkerPop itself.  For example, you reference TinkerPop as a triple store.  I would think of it as: Blueprints enables access to triplestores which would be traversed by Gremlin and could be exposed as a web server with Rexster.